# How to get temp in yahoo weather forecast?

Tags: php, xml, yahoo-weather-api

I have question about RSS yahoo weather forecast.

My case : How Get temp in rss yahoo weather forecast?

my code: I loop:

```
$current = $item->xpath('yweather:condition');<br>
 $forecast = $item->xpath('yweather:forecast');<br>
end loop

{$forecast[0]['day']} - {$forecast[0]['date']} -  {$forecast[0]['text']}. High: {$forecast[0]['high']} Low: {$forecast[0]['low']} || Code :{$forecast[0]['code']}
```

but for `{$forecast[0]['temp']}` not work.

Answer (score 0):

On the Yahoo Forecast the "temp" tag shows only for the current day.

```
<yweather:condition text="Mostly Cloudy" code="26" temp="57" date="Tue, 29 Nov 2005 3:56
      pm PST"></yweather:condition>
```

You should change your code for this one to show the current temperature:

```
{$current[0]['temp']}
```

Also if you want to show the upcoming day's temperatures you should use the "high" and "low" tags only. Check example:

```
      <yweather:forecast day="Tue" date="29 Nov 2005" low="45" high="62" text="Mostly Cloudy"
      code="27"></yweather:forecast>
  <yweather:forecast day="Wed" date="30 Nov 2005" low="52" high="60" text="Mostly Cloudy"
      code="28"></yweather:forecast>
```